OpenSSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:tlsv1 alert internal error with kubernetes and caddy
My domain androz2091.fr is pointing to a single-node kubernetes cluster. Caddy is installed on the node (on the host, not inside k8s), and uses the cluster DNS to redirect to the right service.
Here is my Caddyfile.
Here is my cluster documentation.
Unfortunately, every 30 to 50 requests when accessing my domain, I get this error:
poca@localhost:~ $ wget androz2091.fr
--2024-11-15 10:45:55--  http://androz2091.fr/
Resolving androz2091.fr (androz2091.fr)... HIDDEN-IP
Connecting to androz2091.fr (androz2091.fr)|HIDDEN-IP|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 308 Permanent Redirect
Location: https://androz2091.fr/ [following]
--2024-11-15 10:45:55--  https://androz2091.fr/
Connecting to androz2091.fr (androz2091.fr)|HIDDEN-IP|:443... connected.
OpenSSL: error:14094438:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:tlsv1 alert internal error
Unable to establish SSL connection.

Where do I start looking for the problem?
I have no idea how to debug it (it's not even showing up at each request), and what piece of my cluster could be faulty. I can provide more information if needed.

This error occurs when the remote peer has sent back the internal error alert. Unfortunately TLS does not provide further diagnostic information in the alert codes. But since it is the server that has failed, you have to go looking in the server logs to see if you can determine the cause.

Where do I start looking for the problem? In the packet capture.

I found out why, multiple instances of Caddy were running on my server. One instance was the old one without the right certificate and one was the new working one.
debian@ns561436:~$ ps -fC caddy
UID          PID    PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
root       23093       1  0 Oct18 ?        00:25:44 caddy run --pingback 127.0.0.1:41879
root     1312710       1  0 Oct16 ?        00:29:19 caddy run --pingback 127.0.0.1:33561
root     1316656       1  0 Oct16 ?        00:27:59 caddy run --pingback 127.0.0.1:44115
root     1317619       1  0 Oct16 ?        00:27:34 caddy run --pingback 127.0.0.1:36881
root     1325594       1  0 Oct16 ?        00:25:18 caddy run --pingback 127.0.0.1:46125
root     1531169 1531168  0 Nov30 ?        00:05:09 caddy run
root     2820275 2820274  0 17:31 pts/3    00:00:00 caddy run

Running sudo caddy stop until all the instances were killed made it work.
